# Ignoring everything except for certain subdirectories and their contents

Tags: git, gitignore

So I've seen a few posts that are similar to mine, but none of their answers seems to work for me.

I have a folder structure sort of like the following:

```
|-- identity
|   |-- custom
|   |   |-- pages
|   |   `-- static
|   |-- lib
|   |   `-- ext
|   |-- logs
|   `-- webapps
|-- oxauth
|   |-- custom
|   |   |-- pages
|   |   `-- static
|   |       `-- img
|   |-- lib
|   |   `-- ext
|   |-- logs
|   `-- webapps
`-- oxauth-rp
    |-- logs
    `-- webapps
```

And I want to ignore everything except for the `custom` folders and the contents of them.

I have tried the following ignore file:

```
*
!.gitignore
!/custom/
```

and

```
*
!.gitignore
!/identity/custom/
!/oxauth/custom/
```

But it ignores everything except for my root .gitignore file.

At least that is what it says when I run git status. And there are files under the custom/pages folders.
So, what is it that I am missing?

Comment: Are there files inside all of the directories (or their children) that you want to be including e.g. `lib/ext`? Git doesn't include empty directories

Comment: Yes, I am aware that git doesn't include empty directories. There are files in the directories that I want to include. `lib/ext` is one of the folders that I don't want. I only want to include the custom folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my testing the following should achieve the desired effect.

```
*
!*/
!.gitignore
!/oxauth/custom/**
!/identity/custom/**
```